# Is $H:=\{a\in G: a * s = s * a,\forall s\in S\}$ really a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Let $(G, *)$ be a group and $S\subset G$. How can I show that

$$H:=\{a\in G: a * s = s * a,\ \forall s\in S\}$$
is a subgroup of $G$?

It is easy to show $H\neq \phi$ and $H$ is closed under $*$. But, how about the inversion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a \in H$, then we know
$$ a \ast s = s \ast a $$
for each $s \in S$. Let us multiply by $a^{-1}$ on both the right and the left, to get
$$ a^{-1} \ast a \ast s \ast a^{-1} = a^{-1} \ast s \ast a \ast a^{-1} \,, $$
which simplifies to
$$ s \ast a^{-1} = a^{-1} \ast s \,. $$
Since this holds for all $s \in S$, we have shown that $a^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $H$ is closed under inversion.

Suppose that there is an $a \in H$ such that $a^{-1}$ is not in $H$. Then $a^{-1}*s \not = s*a^{-1}$ for some $s \in S$.
But then right-multiplying both sides by $a$ would give (1) $(a^{-1}*s)*a \not = (s*a^{-1})*a$.

However, on the one hand $(a^{-1}*s)*a = a^{-1}*(s*a) = a^{-1}*(a*s) = a^{-1}*a*s = s$. So this implies that (2) $(a^{-1}*s)*a = s$. On the other hand $(sa^{-1})*a = s*(a^{-1}*a)=s$. So this implies that (3) $(s*a^{-1})*a = s$ as well.

There is no way that (1), (2), and (3) can all hold.